# Can I use pactjs to test microservices that communicate via event streams and message queues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, integration-testing, pact

I wish to implement consumer driven contract testing for an node microservices application. Services communicate via event streams and message queues. All the examples I see of pact for javascript are communicating via http.

So is pact suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/#message-and-asynchronous-support).

Albeit as of 8th May 2018, it is currently experimental (alpha) whilst we iterate on the API and take feedback. It is likely to be rolled into the main library over the next couple of months.